Snowflake Error with CSV Header: ... column "TRANSIENT_STAGE_TABLE"
tl;dr
Snowflake Python Connector: stage csv -> create table -> ProgrammingError: ... data contains more columns ... column "TRANSIENT_STAGE_TABLE" ... but only sometimes...? -> copy into table
Full Situation
Use Case
I am trying to load a bunch of manually created csv files into Snowflake.
Step 1: Working
The following actions produce their intended effects:

I use the Snowflake Python Connector to stage the files into a named stage.

Step 2: Error

I use the below command, adapted from this Medium article, to create a table based on each file:

f"""
create or replace table {table} using template (
  select array_agg(object_construct(*)) 
    within group (order by order_id) 
    from table (infer_schema(
    location=>'@files/{file}',
    file_format=>'public.generic_csv')))
"""

This occasionally produces the following error:
ProgrammingError: 100332 (22000): Error with CSV header: header defined (2) columns while data contains more columns
  File 'my_file.csv.gz', line 22, character 30
  Row 21, column "TRANSIENT_STAGE_TABLE"[2]
  File 'my_file.csv.gz'
  Row 0 starts at line 0, column

Step 3: Working

Copy file into table previously created:

f"""
copy into {table} 
from @webforms 
  files = ( 
    {"'" + file + ".gz'"} 
  ) 
  file_format = ( 
    skip_header = 1
  )
"""

I have downloaded the files that cause the problems. There is never a column not specified, and I don't know why there are these "TRANSIENT_STAGE_TABLE" columns causing problems.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Update 05-30-2024
After updating the field_optionally_enclosed_by parameter to '"', as suggested by NickW, I get a new error at the same spot:
100016 (22000): Field delimiter ',' found while expecting record delimiter '\n'
  File 'my_file.csv.gz', line 22, character 29
  Row 21, column ""My File""["Letters":2]
  If you would like to continue loading when an error is encountered, use other values such as 'SKIP_FILE' or 'CONTINUE' for the ON_ERROR option. For more information on loading options, please run 'info loading_data' in a SQL client.


Appendix
public.generic_csv
create or replace file format generic_csv
  type = csv field_delimiter = ',' 
  parse_header = true
  field_optionally_enclosed_by = '"';

my_file.csv
Year,Letters
2021,AsdfFSeqDSF
2021,AS DF fs eDdsf
2021,asdF AaasDFFe we
2021,asdD. sdf sdDD cSQ
2021,asdF AaasDFFe we
2021,asdF AaasDFFe we
2021,asdF AaasDFFe we
2021,asdF AaasDFFe we
2021,asdflo WSd 123 fs
2021,asdF AaasDFFe we
2021,asdF AaasDFFe we
2021,asdF AaasDFFe we
2022,asdF AaasDFFe we
2022,asdF AaasDFFe we
2022,asdF AaasDFFe we
2022,ASsd jlsf (ASkdl)
2022,asdF AaasDFFe we
2022,asdF AaasDFFe we
2022,asSD asd-asdf
2022,asdF AaasDFFe we
2022,"ASdskdkl josf, asdf"
2022,"ASsslkf jsdf, fao. " 
2022,asdF AaasDFFe we
2022,asdD. sdf sdDD cSQ
2022,asdD. sdf sdDD cSQ
2022,asdD. sdf sdDD cSQ
2022,asdD. sdf sdDD cSQ
2022,asdF AaasDFFe we

Edit: Fixed ordering of events and where the error is created.
Edit 2: Added creation script for public.generic_csv and sample of my_file.csv.
Edit 3: Fixed missing parenthesis in create or replace table... command.

Please update your question with the creation script for the file format public.generic_csv and the contents of the file my_file.csv.gz that is causing the error

@NickW I added those in the appendix (with the my_file.csv being scrubbed of sensitive data, but keeping special the characters that where used). Each of the errors begin at the first occurrence of double quotation marks, which my system generates when a field has commas in the value.

So the only setting you’ve used in your file format is that the field delimiter is a comma - so where you have 2 commas Snowflake thinks there are 3 fields.
If you want to treat everything within quotes as a single field the you would need to use the FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY parameter in your file format

I followed your suggestion. I have updated my question with the new issue, occurring on the same line.

Using your example data and your latest file format, when I run your "create or replace table..." command, it works with no errors (though the command in your question is missing a final ")"
